# firing a function each time a key is pressed (inside for loop)

Tags: javascript

I want to fire a function 10 times, after pressing a key on the keyboard, that means, I press one time, the function gets fired, I press anther time the function gets fired another time.

my code is:

```
function myFunction(a, b) {
   console.log(a + b)
}

for (let i = 0; i <10; i++) {
   window.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
       myFunction("p1", "p2");
   });
}
```

my problem is when press a key the function is fired 10 times at the same time, any help

---

This about the Hanoi Tower problem, I did the recursion, I think it's correct, and I did a function called move(a,b), which move the disks from a container a to b with some animation, all the moves are stocked in an array, then I execute the move function for all those moves, I don't want the move to execute at the same time, I want every move to wait for a keyup to execute

```
let callStack = []
hanoiTower("container1", "container2", 3);

for (let i = 0; i < callStack.length; i++) {
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
window["move"](callStack[i][0],callStack[i][1]);
});
}

/**********************Hanoi Tower function************************* */
function hanoiTower(a, b, n) {

    let c = "container1";
    var containers = [a, b];

    if (containers.includes(c)) c = "container2";
    if (containers.includes(c)) c = "container3";
    if (n == 1) {
        
        callStack.push([a, b])
    }
    else {
        hanoiTower(a, c, n - 1)
        
        callStack.push([a, b])
        hanoiTower(c, b, n - 1);
    }
}

/**************move function****************************/
/*************************************move function*************************** */
function move(c, b) {
    var cn = document.getElementById(c).children;
    let ms = Number(window.getComputedStyle(cn[0]).getPropertyValue("grid-row").split("/")[0]);
    for (let j = 0; j < cn.length; j++) {
        let r = Number(window.getComputedStyle(cn[j]).getPropertyValue("grid-row").split("/")[0]);
        if ((((r < ms) && (r !== 1)) || (ms == 1))) {
            ms = r;
        }
    }
    let n = 0;
    for (let j = 0; j < cn.length; j++) {
        let r = Number(window.getComputedStyle(cn[j]).getPropertyValue("grid-row").split("/")[0]);
        if (r == ms) n = j;
    }
    var top = cn[n];
    //alert(Number(window.getComputedStyle(top).getPropertyValue("grid-row").split("/")[0]));
    document.getElementById(b).appendChild(top);
    //  top.innerHTML=Number(window.getComputedStyle(top).getPropertyValue("grid-row").split("/")[0]);
    let a = document.getElementById(b).childElementCount;
    var y0 = Number(window.getComputedStyle(top).getPropertyValue("grid-row").split("/")[0]);
    var yf = 900 - (a - 2) * 90;
    var inc = 5
    var step = y0;
    frame(); //frame(); frame(); frame(); frame(); frame(); frame(); frame(); frame(); frame(); frame(); frame();
    function frame() {
        document.getElementById(top.id).innerHTML = "yf:" + yf + ",y0:" + y0 + "step:" + step;

        if ((yf > y0) && (Math.abs(step - yf) > inc)) {
            step = step + inc
        } if ((yf < y0) && (Math.abs(step - yf) > inc)) {
            step = step - inc
        }
        document.getElementById(top.id).style.gridRow = step + "/ span 90";
        requestAnimationFrame(frame)
        if (Math.abs(step - yf) <= inc) {
            document.getElementById(top.id).style.gridRow = yf + "/ span 90";
            document.getElementById(top.id).innerHTML = "yf:" + yf + ",y0:" + y0 + "step:" + step;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just take the code out of the for loop. From what I understand, you want to only run the function once per key press?

Comment: yes dear that's what I want, but I don't understand how taking code out of the for loop will help, thank you very much

Comment: What is pb an acronym for??? You should pay more attention to the way you sound when you write, it makes it hard to concisely understand your question.

Comment: Aft3rL1f3, sorry I mean "problem"

Comment: Do you mean that the user should be able to press up only 10 times, and if they press more than that nothing should happen?

Comment: Browser will take care of the loop. That's what events are for, your browser is "spying" what a user does, and if there's something interesting going on, like key presses, the browser will run the function you've passed to `.addEventListener` automatically.

Comment: I did the for loop to fire a function n times where n is the length of an array, and get the arguments p1 and p2 from the array (I really was not clear in presenting my issue, thank you any way)

Comment: this question is not clear at all in what you want to accomplish. we shouldn't have to ask questions, post an answer and then have it down voted because we didn't understand the question.

Comment: You've added ten keypress listeners in the loop. Now when you press a key, all those ten events are firing sequentially. Nikolas has given an answer you can use.

Comment: but why  window.addEventListener('keyup',myFunction)  fires only once

Comment: When JS is running, no events are fired, since both JS and event detecting use the same thread. How likely do you think a user can hit a key when a JS loop goes through ten steps, that takes only some nanoseconds to go ... `addEventListener` doesn't wait for key presses. It's the event queue detecting a keyup event, and then the queue calls `myFunction`, which you've passed (ten times) to the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Have a counter variable that whenever you press the Button, checks wether the function should be fired or not. Increase count with every Button press and when you want to re-enable the Ability to press the button just set the count variable to 0 again.

```
var count = 0;

function myFunction(a, b) {
   console.log(a + b);
}
   
window.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
   if(count < 10) {
       myFunction("p1", "p2");
       count++;
   }
});
```